# Why Linq Prepend() does not work with List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The problem is that I tried to prepend an object to a list and it happened to me that the object wasn't added to the list at all. My code looks like this:

```
List<string> names = GetNames();
string defaultName = "default";
if (!names.Contains(defaultName))
    names.Prepend(defaultName);
```

Funny thing is that when I debug the code, the Prepend() instruction was executed, but nothing happened. Therefore, I have to use List.Insert() to do the task, but I don't understand what happened here?

My name list was just a simple list that contains 4 names, nothing special, and I was using Visual studio 2017 and .Net Framework 4.7 if that be of any help.

Comment: LINQ operations treat their inputs as immutable; you need to use the return value. Try `names = names.Prepend(defaultName);`

Comment: LINQ does not modify the source, and you didn't use the result from Prepend

Comment: The original `List` will not be changed. it returns an `IEnumerable` that starts with the requested element. It is written very clear in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by the guys under the comments already `Prepend` does not modify the source and same applies to all the extension methods in the [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

[Also, mentioned in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> This method does not modify the elements of the collection. Instead,
>   it creates a copy of the collection with the new element.

The solution is to store the value returned from `Prepend` rather than discarding it.

Further, if you want to find a method that actually modifies the source then use `Insert` otherwise you could also create your own `Prepend` extension method:

```
static class Extentions
{
    public static void Prepend<T>(this List<T> source, T element) => source.Insert(0, element);
}
```

You'd use this method exactly the same way you're currently using the `Enumerable.Prepend`, However you must ensure your code is actually calling this version of `Prepend` instead of the one in the `Enumerable` class.

You could remove confusion completely by simply renaming `Prepend` to `PrependToList` if deemed appropriate.